# printing sentence from a word search

Tags: python-3.x

As an exercise in the code below, I've copied and saved Rice's Tarzan novel into a text file (named `tarzan.txt`) and within it, I've searched for "row" and printed out the corresponding lines.

Is it difficult to modify this code so that it searches for the word "row" rather than instances of these letters appearing in another word AND it prints the sentence that contain this word rather than simply the line it appears in? Thanks.
PS - in the code below, I couldn't get lines 3, 5, and 6 to indent properly, despite the 4 space suggestion

```
a="tarzan.txt"  
with open (a) as f_obj:   
    contents=f_obj.readlines()
for line in contents:   
    if "row" in line:  
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
a="tarzan.txt"  
with open (a) as f_obj:   
    contents=f_obj.readlines()
for line in contents:   
    if re.search(r'\brow\b',line):     ####### search for 'row' in line
        print contents.index(line)     ####### print line number
```

Here \b means word boundries.